# Convert and Replace a Column from Text String to Date

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a column which contains numerous dates formatted as below:

[image: Example Sheet]

The exact contents in the cell are: '05-08-2018

I have written various macros to manipulate this etc and a PivotTable and Chart are produced however I am unable to group this column by date. Can you help me with the code required to change this to: "dd/mm/yyyy" so that I can actually use the information as intended?

Thanks in advance for any support.

Comment: Why do you put that ' in front of the date? If you remove that excel can do sorting as intended.

Comment: Actually the `'` is a very effective helping tool in excel to remain values static when you have  different regional setups or needs to keep numbers (00) etc. Otherwise Excel automatically transform the values which can be rather annoying in some circumstances.

Comment: Agreed @Wizhi, but in this case it is the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Wizhi I don't agree with you. A date should **always** be saved as a date/number but never as a text. And the number format to show that date should be at best in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format `YYYY-MM-DD` which is the only human readable format that globally cannot be misunderstood. • If you save dates as text eg `01/02/2018` then neither the computer nor a human can tell if it is actually `DD/MM/YYYY` or `MM/DD/YYYY` this is only possible if it was saved as a number/date.

Comment: I agree with you ;), but always is hard. As far it's possible one should try very hard to store it as a date/number. The problem is if you for example share a document, where some user uses US regional settings while the other uses European settings. If you build some consumption from that table one of the users will experience problem... Either you solve it outside excel or you solve inside excel.. Either way you need to convert it sometimes. But as often you possibly can!!!, you should store it as ISO 8601. Other problem is 00  which disappears, for example phone numbers or serial numbers.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ ISO 8601 is in my opinion underrated. Way **more** people should use it/implement it. It would save a massive headache for many people/organizations :)!!

Comment: I agree on special cases like phone and serial numbers (but recommend to format the column as text instead of adding a `'` for easier user experience). But for dates you can specify *any* date format as number format for your cells (like ISO 8601, US date, English date, …). So it won't ever change to the default localized system settings. This ensures even if you are in Europe if the column is set to US date it will stay US date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use replace function to remove the character "`'`".

```
Sub Replace2()

Dim myValue As String
Dim MyNewValue As String
Dim i As Long

For i = 6 To 10
    myValue = Cells(i, 3).Value
    MyNewValue = Replace(myValue, "'", "")
    MyNewValue = Format(MyNewValue, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    Cells(i, 4).Value = MyNewValue
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the dates from strings to "real" dates.
One method of doing this:

- Select the column
- Select `Data/Text-to-columns` tool
- Next/Next (go to step 3, ensure `-` is NOT selected as a delimiter)
- At Step 3, select the date format corresponding to your data `DMY`
- Next

You will now have "real" excel dates which can be used as such in your Pivot table and chart.